# Rails - uninitialized constant rails (nameerror)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I tried to run a test by running

`bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

but that gave me

`'block in top (required)>':uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)`

It then had a lot more errors at the bottom...

I've read through some stack overflow questions related to this but non worked and i am stuck... Please help!

Thanks!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/njcxc4yos73fj2r/uninitialised%20constant%20rails.PNG

This is the full error!

Comment: show the output of `rvm current` if you are using RVM.

Comment: hi @G.B
I am not using RVM i am using windows! Thanks!

Comment: Show the whole output of the error. It seems that you write "Rails" instead of proper - "rails" somewhere. But, without the output it's impossible to say where exactly.

Comment: @RedZagogulin i've added the full error! please help!

Comment: If i right the problem can be:
1) in your spec_helper.rb in the top op the file find the line "require 'rspec/rails'" - it has to be exactly like this. If there is "require 'rspec/Rails' - it's the problem.
2) If lines above are ok - look for the line under them: "Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }" - it's must be the right route. If it's not, the interpreter can understand the "Rails" as a constant dut to Ruby syntax (cause it's capitalized).

Comment: @RedZagogulin https://www.dropbox.com/s/njcxc4yos73fj2r/uninitialised%20constant%20rails.PNG i dont see any rspec/rails around. the image attached is my spec_helper file...